# Can I get a ResponseEntity (Spring) parametrized with a type either parametrized?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm using `RestTemplate` and `SpringBoot 2.0`.

I have this class which represents a custom JSON response to rest calls.

```
MyCustomResponse<T> {
    private T content;

    public T getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

The code snippet below is a example of use:

```
String LOCALHOST = "http://localhost:8900";

final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");

String url = String.format("%s/ticket/%s", LOCALHOST,  protocol);
final HttpEntity<Ticket> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
```

This works fine:

```
    ResponseEntity<MyCustomResponse> response =
 testRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, RespostaPadrao.class);
```

But it's not what I need, because `getContent` returns a object that looks like:

```
Map< Map < String, Map < String, Map < String, Map < String, Integer >>>>>
```

and because I want to test a Ticket object instead.

In this line, can I use reflection to parametrize the response or this is impossible?

```
ResponseEntity<MyCustomResponse> response = 
  testRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, MyCustomResponse.class);
```

I know how to fix it with  `ResponseEntity<String>` and parse the JSON to my Ticket. But what I really need is know if is possible delegate this task to `RestTemplate` or not.

Thanks!